# Change the listening address to IPv4 from IPv6

Tags: centos, tcp, ipv6, vsftpd, ipv4

I use `netstat -plnt` check the `vsftpd` deamon, it is listening the IPv6(`tcp6`) address, so I use the FileZilla can not connect the VM.

```
[root@localhost src]# netstat -plnt 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2092/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1537/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1540/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1969/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      24464/vsftpd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1537/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1540/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1969/master
```

So, how can I change the `vsftpd` listen port to the IPv4 (`tcp`)?

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `vsftpd.conf` which should be located in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` and update the IPv6 option to NO and Listen to Yes

```
listen Yes
listen_ipv6 NO
```

More info in [vsftpd manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html)

> ```
> NAME
>        vsftpd.conf - config file for vsftpd
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        vsftpd.conf  may  be  used  to  control  various  aspects  of  vsftpd's
>        behaviour. By default, vsftpd looks  for  this  file  at  the  location
>        /etc/vsftpd.conf.   However,  you  may  override  this  by specifying a
>        command line argument to vsftpd.  The  command  line  argument  is  the
>        pathname of the configuration file for vsftpd. This behaviour is useful
>        because you may wish to use an advanced inetd such as xinetd to  launch
>        vsftpd with different configuration files on a per virtual host basis.
> ```
>
> **listen_ipv6**
>
> ```
>       Like  the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6
>       socket instead of an IPv4 one. This  parameter  and  the  listen
>       parameter are mutually exclusive.
>
>       Default: NO
> ```
>
> **listen**
>
> ```
> If enabled, vsftpd will run in standalone mode. This means  that
> vsftpd  must not be run from an inetd of some kind. Instead, the
> vsftpd executable is run once directly. vsftpd itself will  then
> take care of listening for and handling incoming connections.
>
>               Default: NO
> ```

Comment: Make sure you have set `listen=YES` to enable ipv4 otherwise vsftpd will not be able to create IPv4 socket.

Comment: @Yaron I changed the configuration file(`vsftpd.conf`), so I should restart the vsftpd?

Comment: @three-blocks - Yes. You should restart the `vsftpd`

Comment: @Yaron I can not restart it, see there:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371764/job-for-vsftpd-service-failed-because-the-control-process-exited-with-error-code

Comment: @three-blocks - the "Listen=Yes" is required if you are running in standalone mode. In your case, when you aren't running in stand-alone mode, please change it back to "listen=No". i.e. the only change will be in `listen_ipv6` parameter