# Job for vsftpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: linux, centos, vsftpd

I can not restart the `vsftpd`.

```
[root@localhost vsftpd]# service vsftpd restart 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  vsftpd.service
Job for vsftpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vsftpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

---

I use the `systemctl status vsftpd -l` to check:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status vsftpd -l
● vsftpd.service - Vsftpd ftp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-18 17:14:15 CST; 2h 49min ago
  Process: 33103 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 18 17:14:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Vsftpd ftp daemon...
Jun 18 17:14:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 18 17:14:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Vsftpd ftp daemon.
Jun 18 17:14:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit vsftpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 18 17:14:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vsftpd.service failed.
```

---

And be attention, in my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`, I have changed the :

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
```

---

I use the `journalctl -xe`, I get the below information:

```
[root@localhost vsftpd]# journalctl -xe
                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

                                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                      '
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p



                                      (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                  '
```

Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/49-p

```
                                                  (pkla-check-authorization:
                                                  '
```

Jun 18 20:09:46 localhost.localdomain polkitd[33643]: Error evaluating authoriza
li

Comment: Please update your question with `systemctl status vsftpd -l` so output won't be ellipsized. It give some extra intel to look into.

Comment: @ddnomad See my edit

Comment: @three-blocks Check if hostname matches `pasv_address=` in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Comment: @IvanChau No, there is no `pasv_address ` pattern the file's content.

Comment: The `journalctl` output you've pasted was truncated at 80 characters (the usual width of a terminal), so we can't see the useful part of the error message.  Please try again with `--no-pager`.

Answer (score 0):

According to vsftpd config file

```
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
```

so comment out `listen_ipv6=NO` and try again .

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I just follow the below steps

1. make copy of `vsftpd.conf`
2. change `listen=NO` to `listen=YES`
3. change `listen_ipv6=YES`  to `listen_ipv6=NO`
4. Save the file
5. restart vsftp